# Button using text of textview

Tags: java, android, button

I have the following problem:

I want to use the text of a `TextView` which is changing every 10 seconds. With a `Button`, I want to use the text of the `TextView` and show it in another `TextView`.

I tried it with the following code.

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        buttonSave.setClickable(false);
        buttonSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(buttonSave.isEnabled()) {
            String copy = textView.getText().toString();
            settingsview.append("\n" + copy);
        }

        buttonSave.setEnabled(false);
}
```

My problem now is that it works fine until the `TextView` refreshes and then the `TextView` is clearing everything without pressing the button.
This is the code which changes my textfild. The toCheck StringBuilder is a input of OCR which is refreshing every 10secs

```
public void filterit(StringBuilder toCheck){
   Pattern patternDate = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}");
   Matcher matcher = patternDate.matcher(toCheck.toString());
    while (matcher.find()) {

        //textView.setText(matcher.group());
        settingsview.setText(matcher.group());
    }

}
```

Comment: show full code.

Comment: Where your button is getting enabled again?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){


        if(buttonSave.isEnabled()) {
            String copy = textView.getText().toString();
            ettingsview.setText(settingsview.getText().toString()+"\n" + copy);
            buttonSave.setClickable(false);
            buttonSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: it works to copy the text but exactly when the text changes the other textview is deleting the text - i dont understand why

Comment: FYI: the textview is just deleting the text which it receives from the textview

Comment: What are your `TextView` names ?

Comment: they are settingsview and textview, the textview is the one which is changing and the settingsview which is not

Comment: Every time you are setting new text to settingsview, and appending to settingsview. You're not using textview.

Comment: Clearing your settingsview is because `matcher.group()` may be returning empty.